# Can't create virtualenv

Tags: python

I want to create a virtualenv but it doesn't find the command.

```
$ virtualenv venv
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

It is installed:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

What could be causing that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a command without typing the path to the executable, you need to put it (or a symbolic link to it) in one of the the directories where the system looks for executable whenever no path to the command is provided, for example `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`.

So in your case I would put a symbolic link to virtualenv in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
ln -s /path/to/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I am quite new to all this. What shall I put into `/path/to/virtualenv`?

Comment: The path to the virtualenv executable. So since you've used pip to install virtualenv it SHOULD be /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py

Comment: I tried that and it says `File exists`: `$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
ln: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: File exists`. If I try to make a new virtualenv it still doesn't work: `$ virtualenv venv
-bash: virtualenv: command not found`

Comment: try ln -sf ....

Comment: `$ ln -sf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
$ virtualenv venv
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: Permission denied
$ sudo virtualenv venv
Password:
sudo: virtualenv: command not found`

Comment: `$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/ | grep virtualenv
lrwxr-xr-x    1 myname  admin      52 14 Jul 13:09 virtualenv -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py
-rwxr-xr-x    1 myname  admin     445 13 Jul 19:12 virtualenv-clone
-rwxr-xr-x    1 myname  admin   34274 13 Jul 19:12 virtualenvwrapper.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 myname  admin    1388 13 Jul 19:12 virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`

Comment: You need to run the command under superuser mode. so type sudo in front of the command: sudo ln -sf ....  And read a bit about Mac OS X (or Unix/Linux) basics.

Comment: I did `$ sudo virtualenv venv
sudo: virtualenv: command not found`